# Is it possible to prove $\min\{\max\{a,b\},\max\{a,c\},\max\{b,c\}\}=\max\{\min\{a,b\},\min\{a,c\},\min\{b,c\}\}$ without using cyclic symmetry?

Tags: maxima-minima

I want to prove the following identity: For every real numbers $a,b,c,$ 
\begin{gather*}
\min\{\max\{a,b\},\max\{a,c\},\max\{b,c\}\}=\max\{\min\{a,b\},\min\{a,c\},\min\{b,c\}\}.
\end{gather*}
Clearly, let 
 \begin{gather*} 
 L(a,b,c):=\min\{\max\{a,b\},\max\{b,c\},\max\{c,a\}\},  \\
 R(a,b,c):=\max\{\min\{a,b\}, \min\{b,c\},\min\{c,a\}\}.
 \end{gather*} It is clear that $L$ and $R$ are *cyclically symmetric*. Thus, it is easy to prove $L(a,b,c)=R(a,b,c),$ by just considering the case that $a\geq b\geq c.$  But my question is: Can it possible to prove the statement, **without using cyclic symmetry?**

Actually, I have finite proving the first part, as follows:
Because 
\begin{gather*}
 \min\{a,b\}\leq \max\{a,b\},\quad \min\{b,c\}\leq \max\{a,b\},\quad \min\{c,a\}\leq \max\{a,b\},
\end{gather*}
we see that $\max\{a,b\}$ is an upper bound of the set $$\{\min\{a,b\},\min\{b,c\},\min\{c,a\}\},$$ and so, 
$$\max\{\min\{a,b\},\min\{b,c\},\min\{c,a\}\}\leq \max\{a,b\}.$$ Similarly, 
from 
\begin{gather*}
 \min\{a,b\}\leq \max\{b,c\},\quad \min\{b,c\}\leq \max\{b,c\},\quad \min\{c,a\}\leq \max\{b,c\}
\end{gather*}
 we deduce that $$\max\{\min\{a,b\},\min\{b,c\},\min\{c,a\}\}\leq \max\{b,c\},$$ and from
 \begin{gather*}
  \min\{a,b\}\leq \max\{c,a\},\quad \min\{b,c\}\leq \max\{c,a\},\quad \min\{c,a\}\leq \max\{c,a\},
 \end{gather*}
 we see that $$\max\{\min\{a,b\},\min\{b,c\},\min\{c,a\}\}\leq \max\{c,a\}.$$ From above we deduce that 
 the number $$\max\{\min\{a,b\},\min\{b,c\},\min\{c,a\}\}$$ is a lower bound of the set $$\{\max\{a,b\},\max\{b,c\},\max\{c,a\}\},$$ and so $$\max\{\min\{a,b\},\min\{b,c\},\min\{c,a\}\}\leq \min\{\max\{a,b\},\max\{b,c\},\max\{c,a\}\}.$$

But how to prove the converse inequality, that is, $$\min\{\max\{a,b\},\max\{b,c\},\max\{c,a\}\}\leq \max\{\min\{a,b\},\min\{b,c\},\min\{c,a\}\}?$$

Comment: `possible to prove the statement, without using cyclic symmetry?` You could write down the individual cases of sort ordering separately and verify the equality for each. Same idea, just more work.

Comment: @dxiv: Yes, it is certainly OK to do so. But I do not want to prove by cases!

Comment: Maybe you should then explain better why you don't want to use the symmetry, either.

Comment: @dxiv: I just want to find alternative proof. BTW, with the result, I shall prove the following identity concerning gcd and lcm: $([a,b],[b,c],[c,a])=[(a,b),(a,c),(b,c)].$

Comment: It is _not_ correct to assume that $a\geq b\geq c$ if you only have cyclic symmetry; you need full symmetry in the three variables (i.e., symmetry for the entire symmetric group $S_3$, not just a cyclic subgroup).

Comment: @EricWofsey: You are right! Since I think transpositional symmetry is apparent, so I do not mention it.

Comment: I thought for a moment you could simply apply the inequality you proved to $-a, -b, -c$ and use the fact that $\max(x,y,z)=-\min(-x,-y,-z)$. Unfortunately I think that flips the inequality again so you end up with the same thing.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499913/what-divisibility-function-is-between-gcd-and-lcm-with-three-inputs

Answer (score 1):

Let us make a slight generalization, considering not just three variables but $n$ variables where $n\geq 3$. So, let $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$  be an uple of real numbers. Define

$$l_k(x)=\max(x_j,j\neq k), r_k(x)=\min(x_j,j\neq k) \tag{1}$$
and 
$$L(x)=\min_{1\leq k \leq n}l_k(x), R(x)=\max_{1\leq k \leq n} r_k(x) \tag{2}$$

There is a permutation $\sigma$ of $\lbrace 1,2,3,\ldots,n \rbrace$ such that
$x_{\sigma(1)} \leq x_{\sigma(2)} \leq \ldots \leq x_{\sigma(n)}$. Put $y_k=x_{\sigma(k)}$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$. Then

$$y_1 \leq y_2 \leq \ldots \leq y_n \tag{3}$$

Since $l_k(x)=l_{\sigma(k)}(y)$, the sets $\lbrace l_k(x) | 1\leq k \leq n\rbrace$
and $\lbrace l_k(y) | 1\leq k \leq n\rbrace$ coincide. We deduce $L(x)=L(y)$, and similarly $R(x)=R(y)$.

Now, by (3), we have $l_n(y)=y_{n-1}$ and $l_k(y)=y_n$ for $k<n$, so $L(y)=y_{n-1}$. Similary $R(y)=y_2$. Finally,

$$
L(x)=y_{n-1}, R(x)=y_2 \tag{4}
$$

When $n=3$, the two coincide.